# Run WQL query by powershell

Tags: powershell, wql

I want to know how to run WQL query with powershell. 
Here is the WQL query

```
Select UAR.User, UAR.Application, UAR.CurrentState from sms_fullcollectionmembership as FCM
INNER JOIN SMS_UserApplicationRequest as UAR ON UAR.User=FCM.SMSID
where FCM.CollectionID="100104"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [`about_WQL`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679341.aspx) help file, you can either use one of these 2 cmdlets: `Get-WmiObject` or `Get-CimInstance`, or you can use the `[wmisearcher]` type accelerator:

#### Using [`Get-WmiObject`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx):

```
 $queryNameVersion = "Select Name, Version from Win32_Bios"
 Get-WmiObject -Query $queryNameVersion
```

#### Using [`Get-CimInstance`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590758(v=wps.630).aspx):

```
 $queryNameVersion = "Select Name, Version from Win32_Bios"
 Get-CimInstance -Query $queryNameVersion
```

#### Using [`[wmisearcher]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 $searcher = [wmisearcher]"Select Name, Version from Win32_Bios"
 $searcher.Get()
```

`Get-WmiObject` is designed to work with WMI (Microsofts own CIMv2 server implementation), whereas `Get-CimInstance` is supposed to work with any CIMv2 compliant server (although, AFAIK, WQL is specific to WMI).

---

In your example, you could put the query into a [here-string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) to maintain readability:

```
$SCCMQuery = @'
Select UAR.User, UAR.Application, UAR.CurrentState from sms_fullcollectionmembership as FCM
INNER JOIN SMS_UserApplicationRequest as UAR ON UAR.User=FCM.SMSID
where FCM.CollectionID="100104"
'@
$Results = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\Site_Name" -Query $SCCMQuery
```

Comment: Can you please have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324415/double-backslash-in-wmi-wql-query-powershell

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
Get-WmiObject -query $wqlQuery
```

Standard alias is `gwmi`.

Supply the `-namespace` parameter if outside the default WMI namnespace.

(There is also `Get-CimInstance -query …` but I'm unfamiliar with that.)

Comment: Either should work, `Get-CIMInstance` does what `Get-WMIObject` and more, so it does the same regarding WMI queries.