# double backslash in WMI/WQL query powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, wql

I am facing weird issue with my WQL query.

```
$SCCMQuery = @'
Select UAR.User, UAR.Application, UAR.CurrentState from sms_fullcollectionmembership as FCM
INNER JOIN SMS_UserApplicationRequest as UAR ON UAR.User=FCM.SMSID
where FCM.CollectionID="a\100104"
'@
$Results = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\Site_Name" -Query $SCCMQuery
```

Above query is not working properly but when i add another backslash in `FCM.CollectionID` like this(`a\\100104`) then it start working.

Can somebody please advise me why it is working like this? I can't manually put the backslash in all the values as they will later be generated from other WMI query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [about_wql](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679341.aspx) you will see that

> WQL uses the backslash () as its escape
>       character. This is different from Windows
>       PowerShell, which uses the backtick
>       character (`).

In your generated queries you can just artificially add the slash with a simple replace if you wanted.

```
$SCCMQuery.replace("\","\\")
```

I am sure that `$SCCMQuery` was just a testing example but the query has to be placed in the code somewhere.

Comment: yes, you are correct above query is just an example. Can you please give me some example regarding this.

Comment: @404 That depends on what the source of the query is and how you plan on inserting it.

Comment: a\100104 is also coming from WMI query. When i output this value. It is giving me a\100104. Now i have to pass it to another WQL.

Comment: @404 If that is the case I don't see why what me and Mathias suggested would not work. `$resultofFirstQuery.replace("\","\\")`. If you use double quotes for the here string then you can just add the variable directly in the query

Comment: It works perfectly but i am getting one error. Exception setting "CurrentState": "Cannot convert value "Pending" to type "System.UInt32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""

Answer (score 3):

Even though `\` is just a literal character in PowerShell, it's still an *escape character* in WQL.

From [the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250710.aspx):

> WQL uses terminologies and concepts, as specified in [[DMTF-DSP0004]](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0004V2.3_final.pdf),
>   except as noted below, and requires familiarity with the CIM model.
>   **The server MUST treat a backslash as an escape character in a WQL query**, except within a LIKE clause. The server MUST treat literal
>   strings in WQL data as case-insensitive, contrary to what
>   [DMTF-DSP0004] specifies.

Use can use the `-replace` operator to escape the backslash (be aware that the first argument to `-replace` is a regex pattern which also treats backslash as an escape character):

```
$escapedWmiQueryValue = $WmiQueryValue -replace '\\','\\'
```

Comment: But i am putting the value in quote like this 'a\100104' or "a\100104". Is there anyway to achieve.

Comment: PowerShell does not care about the slash in this case... WQL cares regardless

Comment: @404 Single-quotes only prevent the PowerShell parser from interpreting the value one way or another, it's the WMI provider that "misunderstands" you

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarification. Currently user id is like this a\100104. That i will have to pass in WMI by where clause. I can't remove backslash from this. I need to find a way so, WMi can understand it.